# Pythonnet TypeError: No method matches given arguments for

Tags: python, python.net

I have an issue with passing values to `C#` function using `pythonnet`.

I have loaded the `dll` file and when I call a function I receive -
`TypeError: No method matches given arguments for Connect: (<class 'System.UInt64'>, <class 'System.String'>, <class 'System.String'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'System.UInt32'>)`

```
serv = String('121.0.0.1:111')
login = UInt64(1)
empty_string = String(' ')
password = String('password')
time_out = UInt32(1)
cmt = CIMTAdminAPI
pump_mode = cmt.EnPumpModes.PUMP_MODE_MAIL
print(pump_mode)
print(serv)
print(login)
print(password)
print(empty_string)
print(time_out)
connection_serv = cmt.Connect
print(connection_serv)
connection_serv[String, UInt64, String, String, cmt.EnPumpModes, UInt32](serv, login, password, empty_string, pump_mode, time_out)
```

I have tried different things to do. But always receive same result.

those are the values which I need to put

```
Connect(System.String, UInt64, System.String, System.String, EnPumpModes, UInt32)
```

full output from console

```
4
121.0.0.1:111
1
password
 
1
<unbound method 'Connect'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anton\PycharmProjects\work_projects\pynet.py", line 26, in <module>
    connection_serv[String, UInt64, String, String, cmt.EnPumpModes, UInt32](serv, login, password, empty_string, pump_mode, time_out)
TypeError: No match found for given type params
```

Comment: There is no need to specify the type of the variables. For example `password = String('password')` should be like this instead `password = 'password'` and python environment will automatically set password as string

Comment: Unfortunately with this I also receive TypeError: No match found for given type params

Comment: The information you give does not match: you say you give the server string as first param, but the error says that you give a number. Please show the actual code that you run and the error you get with the full log of the prints, maybe the info got mixed up somehow in current post? "<class 'System.UInt64'>, <class 'System.String'>, <class 'System.String'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'System.UInt32'>"

Comment: post edited, as @antont suggested

Comment: I recall having a prob like this but can't remember how solved eventually, may have to do with how the type conversions are made. Is this a proprietary DLL or something publicly available?

Comment: @antont unfortunately, this is proprietary DLL

Comment: I would read the pythonnet source to see how exactly it does the type mapping, maybe add some debug info there so see how it tries to match the types. If it uses strings for the types (classes), maybe namespaces matter, if "cmt.EnPumpModes" != "EnPumpModes" or so.